# How to store GraphObject of facebook in php sdk4 in database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, facebook-php-sdk, user-data

I want to store user interests in database using php mysql.The output is made available in JSON in a tree like structure which I have printed using print_r():

```
  Facebook/GraphUser Object
  (
      [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
           [data] => Array
              (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                 (
                   [category]=> Tours/sightseeing
                   [category_list] => Array
                    (
                      [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                          [id] => 209888929023118
                          [name] => Landmark
                        )
                      [1] => stdClass Object
                        ......
```

My code:

```
  $user_interest = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/interests'))  ->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

For adding data into database I found the following code but it does not work:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($user_interest[data]); $i++) 
{
    $name = $user_interest[data][$i]['name'];
    $category = $user_interest[data][$i]['category'];
    $categoryId = $user_interest[data][$i]['id'];
    //$created_time = $user_interest[data][$i]['created_time'];

    $strsql = "INSERT INTO interests(categoryId,category,name) 
               VALUES($categoryId,$category,$name)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; }
```

Please help I am really stuck here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Here is what I used

```
       $books = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/books'))
        ->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();


  $booksarray=array();
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
      $array = get_object_vars( $books['data'][$i]);
      $booksarray[]=$array['name'];
    }
```

I then simply stored the array in db:

```
 function interests($booksarray, $fbid){
    $query = "INSERT INTO Books      (uid,book1,book2,book3,book4,book5,book6,book7,book8,book9,book10) 
VALUES ('$fbid','$booksarray[0]','$booksarray[1]','$booksarray[2]','$booksarray[3]','$booksarray[4]','$booksarray[5]','$booksarray[6]','$booksarray[7]','$booksarray[8]','$booksarray[9]')";

 mysql_query($query); 
}
```

Any improvement over this would be appreciated. Thanks